# How to select a div after input using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried all of these three but not able to add text to `span` after input dynamically. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(this).next('.error').html('Becareful Baby!');
$(this).closest('br').next('.error').html('Becareful Baby!');
$(this).closest('.error').html('Becareful Baby!');
```

```js
$("input").on("keydown", function(){
  $(this).next('.error').html('Becareful Baby!');
  $(this).closest('br').next('.error').html('Becareful Baby!');
  $(this).closest('.error').html('Becareful Baby!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="nametxt" />
<br />
<span class="error"></span>
```

Comment: `closest` finds only ancestors, not siblings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).next()` will only get you the element after the one you've selected. Providing a selector will then narrow the results further. The element after your input element is the `<br/>`, so that is what `.next()` gives you.

I recommend using `$(this).siblings('.error')`. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/77nvepos/1/

Comment: Hi Jake but this is gonna add text to all possible extisting `.error`

Comment: Use `next().next('.error')` to avoid adding text to all possible siblings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next().next('.error')`. This will y get you the element after the two you've selected. [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```js
$("input").on("keydown", function(){
  $(this).next().next(".error").html('Becareful Baby!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="nametxt" />
<br />
<span class="error"></span>
<span class="error"></span>
```